# Fastest method for spatial differencing (st_difference) a large dataset

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I have a large dataset of polygons where I would like to subtract a unique buffer width from each one, and then difference the buffer from the original polygon. I am working with HydroSHEDS' HydroLAKES database, https://www.hydrosheds.org/products/hydrolakes (Lake polygons shapefile, 820mb), and cropping this file to the extent of Canada/Alaska/continental USA. After cropping to my area of interest, there are ~966,000 rows/observations. Differencing the buffer from the original polygons takes a long time (> 1.5 hr on my computer, even with parallel processing; I have 8 cores and 32GB ram), and I'm therefore wondering what the most efficient method is. Perhaps I'm not parallel processing effectively. Happy to use the data.table package to achieve quicker results if necessary.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)

# generate dataset
hydrolakes_na <- read_sf("HydroLAKES_polys_v10_shp/HydroLAKES_polys_v10_shp/HydroLAKES_polys_v10.shp")
hydrolakes_na <- hydrolakes_na %>% filter(Country %in% c('Canada', 'United States of America'))
hydrolakes_na <- st_transform(hydrolakes_na, 3161) # using st_crs(3161)
ext_of_interest <- st_bbox(c(xmin=-2370387.108629, xmax=3349430.12726586, ymin=9663917.12113056, ymax=16719362.4659996), crs=st_crs(3161)) # desired spatial extent 
hydrolakes_crop <- st_crop(hydrolakes_na, ext_of_interest)

# inward buffer width (in meters)
set.seed(111)
hydrolakes_crop = hydrolakes_crop %>% mutate(inbuff_width = sample(100:1000, nrow(hydrolakes_crop)))

# without parallel processing (note that '-' preceding .$inbuff, to create inward buffer) 
hydrolakes_diff = hydrolakes_crop %>% st_buffer(-.$inbuff_width)
lake_diff = st_difference(st_geometry(hydrolakes_crop), st_union(st_geometry(hydrolakes_diff)))

# with parallel processing
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(4)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

lake_diff = foreach(i=seq_len(nrow(hydrolakes_crop)), .packages=c("sf")) %dopar% {st_difference(st_geometry(hydrolakes_crop[i,]), st_union(st_geometry(hydrolakes_diff[i,])))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised I could solve this by simply converting the polygons to a linestring, and then buffering the inner side of the linestring using singleSide = F. This is much much faster than trying to difference the set of polygons.

```
hydrolakes_line = hydrolakes_crop %>% st_cast("MULTILINESTRING")
hydrolakes_innerbuff = hydrolakes_line %>% st_buffer(-.$inbuff, singleSide=T)
```